# SQL Server xp_cmdshell process wont end with KILL command

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

On a SQL Server instance (Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU31)), I have a job that calls a Python script that makes an API call to return data. This job now and again stops processing (no increase in reads, writes, logical reads are my tell-tale) and I cannot kill the SPID, this leaves the SQL Server Agent thinking the job step is still running so it will not 'finish' the job.

As this instance is a fairly quiet one I had permission to bounce SQL and that got rid of the stuck process from SQL Server's perspective, but it is not a method I employed eagerly. I am assuming this OS process will remain a zombie process until the box is restarted at the next patching job.

Is there a way of identifying the `xp_cmdshell` process at an OS level perhaps, and trying to kill it via CLI? Or could anyone offer any other advice on what my recourse could be in this situation?

For info we have no DBA and I'm  a DEV that is learning as much admin things as possible but there are only so many hours in a day!

Comment: You should be able to just kill the python process, no need to bounce the server? The best way is to fix the python code and either add a timeout or some other way of detecting a stuck API call.

Comment: This server has a whole bunch of python running on it, I have no idea which in the taskmanager is the one of interest or how to go about identifying it. My intention is definitely to fix the python but my immediate concern was the SQL side.

Comment: Sounds like the *real* problem is you're using `cp_cmdshell`.

Comment: You can see the commandline to the python exe and identify it that way, it's an extra column in the task manager. You might also see the `hostprocess` in `sys.sysprocesses` for the xp_cmdshell, it *might* point you to the correct process

Comment: You can use `sp_execute_external_script` for Python or R, which is much more robust https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-external-script-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 In the meantime, use Process Explorer  from Sysinternals to identify which `python.exe` process is the child of SQL Server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: @siggemannen getting the hostprocess sounds may well help me find it to kill it as an OS level, thanks.

Comment: @Charlieface I will look into 'sp_execute_external_script' and process explorer, thanks.